# MongoDB suddenly won't start

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi

I have been running MongoDB on a RPI for several weeks, and suddenly it won't start. I know there's a lot of similar questions where correcting the permissions seemed to work. However, this has not worked for me.

I suspect a power off of the RPI has caused this problem, but I have no idea how to solve it.

I get the following terminal output:

```
$ sudo service mongodb start 
[FAIL] Starting database: mongodb failed!
```

More details are shown with the 'mongod' command:

```
$ mongod
db level locking enabled: 1
mongod --help for help and startup options
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4036 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=raspberrypi
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten]
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.1.1) of MongoDB.
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten]
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten]
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] db version v2.1.1, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] git version: f457ff42ec37f2562d1a5ff06b4d96a861414c94
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] build info: Linux piplusraspbian 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014 armv6l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] options: {}
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 dbexit:
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Fri Aug 28 14:04:06 dbexit: really exiting now
```

The /data/db does exist and seem to have the right permission:

```
$ ls -l /data
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug 28 14:37 db
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug 28 09:44 db_backup
```

The content of db has been copied to db_backup to check if that did any change, but it didn't. The db content permissions also seem fine:

```
$ ls -l /data/db_backup
total 131100
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb     4096 Aug 28 09:44 client-db
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Aug 28 09:44 client-db.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 33554432 Aug 28 09:44 client-db.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Aug 28 09:44 client-db.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb        0 Aug 28 13:52 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb     4096 Aug 28 09:44 myproject
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Aug 28 09:44 myproject.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 33554432 Aug 28 09:44 myproject.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 16777216 Aug 28 09:44 myproject.ns
```

I have also tried mongod --repair, but it does not help.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I don't care about the data, as it is all just temporary testing data.

Comment: According to your message `Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`. 1. `ps aux | grep mongod` doesn't indicated other instance running? 2. What is the permissions for `/data/db/mongod.lock`?

Comment: I tried mongod --shutdown, but it said no instance was running. Before I removed mongod.lock, the permission was mongodb:mongodb. Now there is no such file - I thought the file might contain errors and hoped that Mongo would create a new clean one...

Comment: I just double checked, and I actually think that an instance was running from a startup script, but for some reason I was unable to shut it down. After removing the startup script and rebooting the RPI, I could run repair, then correct the permission on /data/db and then it was running again! Thanks for guiding me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

There is a **mongod.lock** file inside the mongo's data directory, normally is **/var/lib/mongodb**. The content of this file is the **pid** of the mongod process.

If the mongod is stopped, the content of this file should be empty. Otherwise the mongod was stopped unexpectedly. To fix and start a new mongod process, assuming that mongo's data directory is **/var/lib/mongodb**. Just clear the file...

```
$ echo "" > /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

and start a new mongod process.

```
$ mongod
```